# IOS/JSON: Store float value in object variable

Tags: ios, core-data

An API I am using returns some JSON that includes many decimal values between 0 and 1--basically probabilities--such as .422323.

I need to store this value in Core Data.  My understanding is that the correct variable type for that type of number is a float value (or possibly double.)

However, in order to store values in core data, I am having to wrap them in NSNumber wrappers using something like:

```
[newPoi setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:someFloat] forKey:@"yCoordinate"];
```

Given this overhead which will be considerable  as I have many operations that use these numbers, is there a better variable type for storing values such as .422323?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Float` attribute type should serve you well enough.
Yes, by default Core Data wraps all primitive types to provide an object oriented interface (which is a desired behaviour commonly).
More than an overhead, for syntactical sugaring you can choose to use `Scalar Type` attributes.
You can toggle to `Use Scalar Type` in the `Data Model Inspector` panel.

[image: Use Scalar Type]

Now, on creating the `ManagedObject Subclass` from `Editor` menu, you'll get:
`@property (nonatomic) float yCoordinate;`

Comment: If I check that does it mean I can just use use the attribute without converting to floatValue?  Or do I have to do something like int64_t yCoordinate